# How can I correctly specify both types for a mock with ts-sinon?

Tags: typescript, sinon

Is there a way to declare the type on a `ts-sinon` stubbed constructor such that typescript understands that both the properties and methods from `ts-sinon` and the mocked class are available?

The code below works, but I'd like a more specific type on `foo` than `any`:

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';
import * as sinon from 'ts-sinon'

class Foo {
  public getFoo(): string {
    return 'foo';
  }
}

describe('Foo', () => {
  it('can mock methods on Foo', () => {
    // How can I specify a specific type that will allow properties
    // and methods from both Foo and the stubConstructor return? 
    let foo: any = sinon.stubConstructor(Foo);
    foo.getFoo.returns('bar');
    expect(foo.getFoo()).to.equal('bar');
  });
});
```

I've tried types such as `Foo | sinon.StubbedInstance<Foo>` but haven't been able to find one that works.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently just `sinon.StubbedInstance<Foo>` includes both sets. I finally got it to work just after posting the question.

I.e

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';
import * as sinon from 'ts-sinon'

class Foo {
  public getFoo(): string {
    return 'foo';
  }
}

describe('Foo', () => {
  it('can mock methods on Foo', () => {
    let foo: sinon.StubbedInstance<Foo> = sinon.stubConstructor(Foo);
    foo.getFoo.returns('bar');
    expect(foo.getFoo()).to.equal('bar');
  });
});
```